# JTable change cell colors using TableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, cellrenderer

I am using a JTable in my GUI application as a grid to represent positions for a game. I want the cells of the table that represent a certain position of an object to have a certain color, and on some actions, the object to move (i.e the color cell to move around in the Grid /JTable). I know that I can change cell colors by making a class that extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer` , is this the only way it can be done? or is there a simpler way to chage cell colors??Also Is JXTable better than JTable for such an application ?

**EDIT:** I didn't include the fact that I need certain cell colors to change dynamically, i.e with button clicks, keyboard clicks ...etc, is that still possible with any `TableCellRenderer` in case I am still using JTable ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JTable, DefaultTableCellRenderer is the best way to do it.

However, if you use JXTable, it'll be much easier to use a Highlighter and a custom Predicate. Generally, Predicates are used to color based on contents of the cell, but you could just as easily have it color based on row/column and some external value.

Look in http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-core/1.6.2/swingx-core-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html under Rendering and Highlighting, which is a striped table and pattern matching. You'd essentially do the same thing as the pattern highlighter, but with your own Predicate.

Comment: How can do this dynamically though? Does it work the same way if I need to click a button that change a cell color, or make a keyboard click change cell colors as well? Thanks You

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, consider using [`prepareRenderer()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29), as suggested by @mKorbel and shown in the article [*Table Row Rendering*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

Comment: can I use prepareRenderer() on a button action to change a color of one cell or a set of cells?

Comment: Yes, if the state is a pure function of row & column. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798980/jtable-disable-checkbox-in-cell/5799016#5799016).