# Change the color of the Java Swing Component Focus indicator

Tags: java, swing, focus, indicator

I have a JPanel with a JButton, JTextField and a JTable, and the TAB key traverses these components as expected with a little black box drawn around the component (or cell in case of the JTable) that has focus.  How can I change the color of the black-box focus indicator?

Answer (score 4):

The selection appearance is under the control of each component's UI delegate, discussed in [*How to Set the Look and Feel*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

As a concrete example, on certain L&Fs, you can override the default value when your program starts up:

```
UIManager.put("Button.focus", Color.red);
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me a step forward.  What I'm trying to figure out is why some JTables in a large application have the focus indicator and some don't.  I used:  UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder",new BorderUIResource(new LineBorder(new Color(255,0,0)));  And those JTables with focus indicators changed to red but I still don't see the focus indicator on all JTables.  Any idea why a cell in a JTable wouldn't show the focus indicator?

Comment: @splatek but that topic for new question, with your code ... http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

Comment: @mKorbel is correct. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873665/jtable-row-selection-background-problem/6874437#6874437) that works with your border; it might make a good [sscce](http://sscce.org/). You also might look for a `null` border setting.

Comment: @mKorbel All this is new to me but I took your comment to mean open a new question instead on continuing with this one.  So I did.