# Increase the thickness of the border of the focused area in swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jgoodies

I have a problem with Java Swing and the LAF.
I am using JGoodies and I tried to increase the thickness of the border of the focused area. I tried it via the UIDefault but there is no such option. [example of the Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMtnb.png) Can you give me a hint how to set the border?

I saw this post: [Change the color of the Java Swing Component Focus indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877603/change-the-color-of-the-java-swing-component-focus-indicator) but there is no solution to my problem.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMtnb.png)

Comment: What Border? Components like JCheckBox, don't have a Border. A JTextField has a single line Border. A JButton has a thicker Border. So each component has a Border that suits the component. So there is no one step solution that fits all components. I don't know why you would try to change the LAF.

Comment: What do you mean by _the focused area_? Do you mean the [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) that currently has the keyboard [focus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)?

Comment: e.g. if the table is focused it gets a blue selection border. i tried to add a picture in the original post but it doesn´t seemed to work. i will try to add the Screenshot again

Comment: Do you mean something like this image: https://imgur.com/giDIvnM

Comment: Yes exactly the blue boarder around the table. not the row selection

Answer (score 0):

This style depends on the L&F, if it supports the `Table.border` propriety or the `Table.scrollPaneBorder`.

In some cases, this property `Table.scrollPaneBorder` is enough but there aren't rules to have the table wrapped inside the scroll pane wrap table. In other words, you can have a table without a scroll panel.

if you have a table without scroll panel, the problem can be resolve from LookAndFeel, if your actual L&f doesn't have this support, the solutions are multiple, such as:

- Use another l&f. such as [Material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing), the table.border is under the developing branch, you can compile the source.
- Develop a personal TableUI to set the border inside the UI such as the point one
- you can wrapper your table inside a scroll pane, but it should respect the L&f rules.

### 1. Implement the Table UI. (from [material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing))

insert a Border inside the propriety `Table.border`, such as:

`UiManager.put("Table.border", new BorderUIResources(YOUR_BORDER));`

You need to wrap the border inside the BorderUIResource because, if you implement the switch L6f inside your APP, Swing doesn't remove the propriety without the UIResource interface.

```java
public class MaterialTableUI extends BasicTableUI {


    public static ComponentUI createUI (JComponent c) {
        return new MaterialTableUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI (JComponent c) {
        super.installUI (c);
        table.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.border"));
    }
}
```

This answer makes an overview of all possible solutions that exist if the table is unwrapped from the Scroll Pane. In fact the propriety `Table.scrollPaneBorder` should be work fine

### Example with material-ui-swing

set border

`UIManager.put("Table.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(MaterialColors.COSMO_BLACK, 5));`

[image]