# JTable trouble changing colors for first column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i try to change the color of fields in a JTable according to their value. I don't want to change any color of the first column but it changes anyway in a buggy way(some fileds are not correctly filed like University and Possible_Reviewer):[image: x is the first column]

My code is as following:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomRenderer());

private class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus, int row, int col){
         Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,  value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
         try {
             Double val =  Double.parseDouble(value.toString());

             if(col == 0){
                 comp.setBackground(Color.white);
             } else {
                 comp.setBackground(changeColor(val));
             }
         } catch (NumberFormatException e){}
         return( comp );
    }

    private Color changeColor(Double val) {
        //returns a Color between red and green depending on val
    }
}
```

The weird  thing is that when i use "col == 2" it turns the second column white but the first remains strangely colored.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend JTable class and override this method:

```
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column){}
```

Otherwise JTable will use the same renderer for each cell in the same column.

EDIT:

Like @Mark Bramnik pointed out, it's better to not instantiate a new TableCellRenderer object for every getCellRenderer call. You could implement a method like the following:

```
setCellRenderer(int row, int col, TableCellRenderer render)
```

and store the renderer in the extended JTable itself.

Comment: hi, note that you shouldn't return each time a new object of renderer from the getCellRenderer, otherwise in big tables it will be just too much objects in vain, and you can encounter performance-related issues. Try to minimize the amount of different renderer objects.

Comment: @Mark Bramnik: yes I know that. I usually implement a setCellRenderer(int row, int col, TableCellRenderer render) and store the renderer in the extended table itself. I'll edit my answer thanks.

Comment: +1 A limitation of this approach is that it affects the _view_ column.

Comment: @trashgod: could you explain a bit more about this limitation? I'm not sure to have understand.

Comment: Oops, my error; the problem would accrue to overriding `prepareRenderer()`.

Comment: -1 for over-complicating ;-) There is very rarely any reason for a per-cell renderer, per-column is fine-grained enough. Besides, the renderer itself is designed to deal with configuration down to the cell, simply use a well-behaved implementation (note that DefaultTableCellRenderer is _not_ well-behaved) and do all config there as appropriate

Comment: @kleopatra what type of TableRenderer you'll preferred in all cases, what was/were your first word(s) in your mind,

Answer (score 3):

[*How to Use Tables: Using Custom Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) mentions this alternative approach: "To specify that cells in a particular column should use a renderer, you use the [`TableColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html) method [`setCellRenderer()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setCellRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29)."

Addendum: A benefit of this approach is that the renderer "sticks" to the column if the user drags it to a different position. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798980/jtable-disable-checkbox-in-cell/5799016#5799016), replace `setDefaultRenderer()` with `setCellRenderer()`.

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(DATE_COL).setCellRenderer(new DateRenderer());
```

Comment: doesn't setCellRenderer use the same renderer for each cell in the same column?

Comment: Yes, but you can condition the appearance according to value, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798980/jtable-disable-checkbox-in-cell/5799016#5799016).