# Change only one cell's color in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, cell, background-color

I know I can set the whole column's background color with this code, but how can I set a different color for each cell? I have a table with two columns and one to one thousand rows.

```
words.getColumn("columnNameHere").setCellRenderer(
    new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText(value.toString());
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            return this;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Also consider overriding `prepareRenderer()`, compared to `TableCellRenderer` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row and column number are passed into `getTableCellRendererComponent`. So you could do something like:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setText(value.toString());
    if (row==12 && column==2) {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    return this;
}
```