# JTable Customized Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I would like some input on how to implement the following row rendering. I don't need actual code but just the concept.
Row 1 is Yellow and Row 2 is White. My bean has Order Date, Req Ship Date, ... and Product as properties.
[image]

Comment: Have a look into [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)

Comment: Google "Java Swing JTable alternating colors" and I got http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/01/java_tip_how_add_zebra_background_stripes_jtable

Comment: Two approaches are compared [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513).