# JTable Renderer not working with RowSorter?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablesorter, cellrenderer

I have a Simple JTable holding Integers in the first column and Strings in the Second. I would like to be able to sort each Column.

My Renderer:

```
    package gui.table;

import gui.DaimlerColor;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StandardCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground((isSelected ?  DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE : (row % 2 == 1 ? DaimlerColor.DARK_WHITE : DaimlerColor.WHITE)));
        if(isSelected){
            c.setBackground(DaimlerColor.LIGHT_BLUE);
        }
        return c;   
    }
```

}

My TableModel:

```
package gui.table;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.jdom2.Element;

import reporting.FailureClassificationCatalogue;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ReportTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    public ReportTableModel(List<Element> reports) {

        super(createDataVector(reports), createColumnNames());
    }

    private static Vector<Vector<Object>> createDataVector(List<Element> reports) {

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new  Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < reports.size(); i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            if(reports.get(i).getName().equals("Default")){
                row.add("-");
            }
            else{
            row.add(Integer.valueOf(i+1));
            }
            String title = reports.get(i).getAttributeValue("type");
            try{
                title = FailureClassificationCatalogue.valueOf(title).getName();
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){

            }catch(NullPointerException npe){

            }
            row.add(title);
            data.add(row);
       }
       return data;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
        switch (colNum) {
            case 0:
                return Integer.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    } 

    private static Vector<String> createColumnNames() {
        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>(); 
        columns.add("Number");
        columns.add("Error Type");
        return columns;
    }

    /**
     * overridden to ignore null values
     */
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        // delegate to the parent method
        super.setValueAt(value, row, col);
    }
}
```

If I don´t implement the getColumnClass then the renderer works fine but the Integers are sorted as Strings. As soon as I implement the method the renderer doesn´t work properly (background is only set in one column) but the Integers are sorted correctly. How can I resolve this?

My Code to set the renderer and sorter:

```
reporttable = new JTable();
        reporttable.setName("report");
        reporttable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        reporttable.setRowHeight(40);
        reporttable.addMouseListener(tgc.mouseListener);
        reporttable.setDefaultRenderer( Object.class, new StandardCellRenderer());
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>();
            reporttable.setRowSorter(sorter);
            sorter.setModel(reportModel);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Absent an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), <strike>two</strike> several things stand out:

1. The call to `setDefaultRenderer()` should specify the data type to which it applies, e.g. `String.class` or `Integer.class`. Alternatively, override the table's `prepareRenderer()` to consider all cells, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513).

   ```
   reporttable.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new StandardCellRenderer());
   ```
2. Your `TableRowSorter` constructor "Creates a `TableRowSorter` with an empty model." Instead, pass your `TableModel` to the constructor or use `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`.

   ```
   reporttable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
   ```
3. "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates," as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: where should the prepareRenderer() method be overwritten? DefaultCellRenderer does not have this method.

Comment: @Hans En few times is touched convertXxxToXxx in questions here, tagged by RowSorter/RowFilter (sorting/filtering) for prepareRenderer or TableCellRenderer too,