# How to Change a jTable's Cell Color using a Cell's Designated Row and Column?

Tags: java

I want a button when clicked, calls upon a method that changes a `jTable` object's cell colors. Something like:

```
jTableName.setCellBackground(Color, row, column)
```

Bringing me to a method as close or similar to this would really help me right now.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

> You can use DefaultTableCellRenderer to color alternate row from JTable.
>
> table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer(){
>      private DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER =  new >DefaultTableCellRenderer();
>
> ```
>        @Override
>        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object >value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
>            Component c = >DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, >hasFocus, row, column);
>            if(isSelected){
>                c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
>            }else{
>            if (row%2 == 0){
>                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
>
>            }
>            else {
>                c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
>            }     }
>
>   //Add below code here
>            return c;
>        }
>
>    });
> ```
>
> If you want to color your row using the value of a particular row then you can >use something like this. Add these line to above
>
> `if(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getIdentifier().equals("Status")){//Here`Status`is column name
>       if(value.toString().equals("OK")){//Here`OK`is the value of row`
>
> ```
>    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
> ```
>
> }

This is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618295/6451318)