# Java - Change row color based on cell content

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I have a Java application that shows things from a database. I would like to modify the colour of the rows based on the content of a cell. I tried to insert an `if` cycle in the data retrieving process from databse using `setBackground` property but without succeding in that.

Here there is code. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class TableFrame2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String user = "root";
                String password = "";
                TableFrame2 frame = new TableFrame2(user, password);
                frame.setVisible(true);             


            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @return 
     */

    public TableFrame2(String user, String password) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 399, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setEditingColumn(0);
        table.setEditingRow(0);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        model.addColumn("iD");
        model.addColumn("name");
        model.addColumn("type");
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 200)); 
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        try {
            String dateMerged = "2015-01-30";//yearField.getText() + "-" + monthField.getText() + "-" + dayField.getText();

            Connection connection = MysqlConnector.dbConnection(user, password);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM booking, band WHERE room_idRoom = 2 AND idBand = band_idBand AND dateBooking BETWEEN '" +dateMerged+" 00:00:00' AND '" +dateMerged+" 23:59:59'";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                String bandName = rs.getString("nameBand");
                String bookingType = rs.getString("typeBooking");
                String bookingId = rs.getString("idBooking");
                model.addRow(new Object[] { bookingId, bandName,bookingType });

                if (bookingType == "Recording"){
                    table.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use custorm `TableCellRenderer`, read more in [tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which allows you do to custom rendering without creating multiple custom renderers for the different data types in your table.