# How to Highlight row table if given a condition?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

I have a jtable which is consists of columns :

```
C No, Borrower, Market, Loan, Start, Daily, Expiry
```

how can i highlight the table row if the current date is 5 days away from the date inside the column `'expiry'`?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
            Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();           
            String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
            System.out.println(expDateString);
             String nana = tableSummary.getModel().getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
            System.out.println(nana);


            for(int i=0; i<=tableSummary.getRowCount()-1; i++){

                   if(nana.compareTo(expDateString)>=0){                           
                       rowrenderer.setBackground(Color.RED);

                   }
             }
```

Comment: You've given no information that anybody could use to help you.  Are you producing HTML, or is this a Swing app? What js framework are you using, if any? Are you running Tomcat and JSPs, or another JEE container?  Please read the [FAQ] and [ask] before posting.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Right there in the unedited question it says "jtable" so obviously this is related to Swing. It is a reasonable question which, I think, has enough information to be answered. Might be a good idea to withdraw the down-vote.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. Yeah it is in java, related to Swing since it is jtable.

Comment: `jtable` is overloaded. There's even a jtable.org for a JQuery plugin by that name.

Comment: be sure you understand how the renderer mechanism is working http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html (looping through the values and set some backgrounds doesn't make any sense)

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to highlight every cell in the same row as a qualifying `Expiry`, you should override [`prepareRenderer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29), as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513) and discussed in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797920/230513). You can determine a matching row using the methods of `Calendar. getInstance()`, and you can change the color using the renderer's `setBackground()` method.

Comment: can i ask for an example? i am not quite familiar yet with cellrenderer. thanks

Comment: Oops, sorry for the broken link; I've updated the answer above. The best examples are in [*Table Row Rendering*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).