# How to set color to a certain row if certain conditions are met using java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have A jtable. (tablesummary). one of it's column is EXPIRY. i want to highlight the row with the client whose expiry date already lapsed on the current date..

i already got the logic but i can't make the row turn red or any other colors. 
here's my code:

```
         int count = (tableSummary.getRowCount());
         NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");          
         String no = formatter.format(count);
         txtNo.setText(no);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
            Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();           
            String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

            for(int i=0; i<=tableSummary.getRowCount()-1; i++){
                String nnn= tableSummary.getModel().getValueAt(i, 6).toString();   
                System.out.println(nnn);
                int res = nnn.compareTo(expDateString); 
                    if(res>=0){
                        System.out.println("if ni " + (res>=0));
                    }
                    else{ 
                        System.out.println("else ni" + (res>=0));
                        rowrenderer.setBackground(Color.RED);


                    }                        
            }
```

can anyone help me with this? because it's one of the main highlight of my interface.
Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: show the definition of "rowrenderer".

Comment: you forgot to add the code for your cellrenderer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Highlight row table if given a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714110/how-to-highlight-row-table-if-given-a-condition)

Comment: As noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9718691/230513), you should be storing a `Date` in your `TableModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following link, you can find an example of the action you want to do: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SadingRows.shtml

You have to override `prepareRenderer()` on `JTable` and add the backgroundColor on the `Component` that gets returned.

PS: for future reference, it would be easier if you would include more code. The definition of  your `rowrenderer` =)

**EDIT**

Instead of your normal `JTable table = new JTable(model)` declaration, use the following (change the logic in the `prepareRenderer` method if you want something else than an alternating color):

```
JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int Index_row, int Index_col) {
        // get the current row
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, Index_row, Index_col);
        // even index, not selected
        if (Index_row % 2 == 0 && !isCellSelected(Index_row, Index_col)) {
            comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

Comment: i don't have any definition yet for the rowrenderer. I was just showing it for the reason that i have a bit of an idea that i should be using that but really don't know how to code it

Answer (score 8):

... described in previous threads and answers, only example

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePrepareRenderer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;
    private Date maturityDate = new Date();
    private Date todayDate = new Date();
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    private Date tableDate = new Date();
    private String strDate = "";
    private Date modifDate = new Date();
    private Calendar cal;

    public TablePrepareRenderer() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Date"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50), new Date()},
            {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), new Date()},
            {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), new Date()},
            {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00), new Date()}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                /*int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.blue);
                } else {
                ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }*/
                if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (table.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                        String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                        c.setBackground("Buy".equals(type) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.GREEN);
//
                        maturityDate = new Date();
                        todayDate = new Date();
                        strDate = sdf.format(todayDate);
                        try {
                            todayDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
                        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(TablePrepareRenderer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        tableDate = (Date) table.getValueAt(row, 4);
                        strDate = sdf.format(tableDate);
                        if (strDate != null) {
                            if (!strDate.isEmpty()) {
                                try {
                                    maturityDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
                                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(TablePrepareRenderer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                                if (maturityDate != null) {
                                    int mmDiffDealToValue = (maturityDate).compareTo(todayDate);
                                    if (((mmDiffDealToValue < 0))) {
                                        c.setBackground(Color.orange);
                                        c.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
//
                    }
                }
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }
                return c;
            }
        };
        modifyDateInTable();
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void modifyDateInTable() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(modifDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, - 1);
        modifDate = c.getTime();
        table.setValueAt(modifDate, 0, 4);
        c.setTime(modifDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, +5);
        modifDate = c.getTime();
        table.setValueAt(modifDate, 1, 4);
        c.setTime(modifDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
        modifDate = c.getTime();
        table.setValueAt(modifDate, 1, 4);
        c.setTime(modifDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, - 16);
        modifDate = c.getTime();
        table.setValueAt(modifDate, 3, 4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TablePrepareRenderer frame = new TablePrepareRenderer();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, `Renderer` is always so confusing for me, though no doubt, one can do amazing thingies with them. Learned something new, with this :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
public class TablePrepareRenderer extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;

    public TablePrepareRenderer() {
        Object[] columnNames = { "Type", "Company", "Name", "Salery", "Designation" };
        Object[][] data =
        { { "Probation", "Digital Research Lab", "Kamran Ali", "500,000", "Java Developer" }, { "Permenent", "Netsole",
                                                                                                "Farhan Khan",
                                                                                                "80,000",
                                                                                                "System Administaror" },
          { "Contract", "System Limited", "Danyal", "100,000", "Network Administrator" },
          { "Probation", "TeraData", "Ali Raza", "45,000", "IT Officer" },
          { "Contract", "MicroSoft", "Sikandar Hayat", "450,000", "Team Lead" },
          { "Permenent", "MicroSoft", "Adnan", "30,000", "Driver" }, };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {


            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {
                @Override
                public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

                    if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                        if (table.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                            String type = (String)getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Probation")) {
                                c.setBackground(new Color(198, 190, 255));

                            }
                            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Permenent")) {
                                c.setBackground(new Color(14, 255, 190));

                            }
                            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Contract")) {
                                c.setBackground(Color.green);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                        ((JComponent)c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                    }
                    return c;
                }
            };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TablePrepareRenderer frame = new TablePrepareRenderer();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setSize(800, 500);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }
}
```