# setSelectionBackGround() doesn't set color for custom rendered cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a custom CellRenderer (an instance of TableCellRenderer) to render the Cells of CLOSE column depicted below. I have set a color for the table's  setSelectionBackGround but the cells of the said column's bg color doesn't get painted when selected. please provide me with any insight for which I shall be extremely grateful.

[image]

Here is my TablecellRenderer Class

```
class LabelRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

Font f;
Color selectionBG;    
Color upDirection;

LabelRenderer(){
    super();
    f=new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 12);
    selectionBG = new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255);
    upDirection= new Color(0,102,0);
}


@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(   JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,  int row, int column) {
    //structure of passing array (value)
    // new Object[]{boolean direction, String close (change%)}

    Object arr[] = (Object[])value;

    Boolean direction = (Boolean)arr[0];

    if( direction )
        this.setForeground(upDirection);//GREEN
    else
        this.setForeground(Color.red);

    this.setText(arr[1].toString());
    this.setFont(f);


    return this;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: When user select a specific row , I want to paint all the columns in the specified color.

Comment: oi Vishal K, thanks for nothing. :P

Comment: You already have two informative and complete answers .. What else are you looking for??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your renderer extends `JLabel` which is not opaque by default. You can execute `setOpaque(true)`in the renderer . Or alternatively you can extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` which is opaque by default. For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableBgDemo {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object[][] rows = { { "Column 1", "Column 2" },
                { "Column 1", "Column 2" }, { "Column 1", "Column 2" },
                { "Column 1", "Column 2" } };

        Object[] columns = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns);

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        table.setSelectionBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, row, column);
            c.setForeground(Color.RED);
            return c;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using a custom CellRenderer (an instance of TableCellRenderer) to
>   render the Cells of CLOSE column depicted below. I have set a color
>   for the table's setSelectionBackGround but the cells of the said
>   column's bg color don't get painted when selected. please provide me
>   with any insight for which I shall be extremely grateful.

issue is caused by two mistakes

1. your Renderer, don't use this code, here are a few excelent code, (I'd be use prepareRenderer for RowRenderer)
2. never to set, modify, add value that came from Model, meaning code line `this.setText(arr[1].toString());`, Renderer is about highlighter, decorator

Comment: +1 for `prepareRenderer`. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/1048330) or [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) by @camickr.