# Java JTable Alternate Row Color not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Why this following code not working? where is the problem?
My jTable is initiated as jTable1;

```
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new TableCellRenderer(){

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component c = (Component) table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                c.setBackground(row%2==0 ? Color.white : Color.yellow);                        
                return c;
            };

        });
```

Answer (score 23):

Recently while going through the  source code of javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer, I found following simple solution which will provide alternate row coloring for all tables in an application.

In the code, just after setting default look and feel insert following code:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
if (defaults.get("Table.alternateRowColor") == null)
    defaults.put("Table.alternateRowColor", new Color(240, 240, 240));
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I learned, that reading documentation & source code actually can help :-)

Comment: Note: custom cell renderers may override the background color.

Comment: How to use this? I'm new to netbeans

Answer (score 5):

- override [prepareRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29) for decorating whole row
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/714968) based on [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) by @camickr

Answer (score 4):

```
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            c.setBackground(row%2==0 ? Color.white : Color.yellow);                        
            return c;
        };
    });
```

The main error is the querying of the table for its renderer. If you have other column renderers you have to solve it there too.

Comment: It shows super.getTableCellRendererComponent symbol not found

Comment: Corrected the answer, I almost always use the DefaultTableCellRenderer, and oversaw you using the interface.

Answer (score 2):

The Correct answer is as follows for me...

```
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer(){
            private DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER =  new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component c = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                if (row%2 == 0){
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }                        
                return c;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.putIfAbsent("Table.alternateRowColor", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

This will affect all the tables in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.... [REFER](http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/default/2007/03/15/JTable-Row-Alternate-Row-Background)

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
        Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        Color alternateColor = new Color(252,242,206);
        Color whiteColor = Color.WHITE;
        if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())){
            Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : whiteColor);
            returnComp .setBackground(bg);
            bg = null;
        }
        return returnComp;
};
```