# JTable how to change row color?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Why are my table(2) rows are all the same color? How can I make it grey row white row like in the table marked 1?

[image: 2 is my table 1 is table on the internet]

Comment: The Nimbus look and feel will do this by default, otherwise you'll have to roll your own solution, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279727/java-abstracttablemodel-2-different-color-for-each-row/25279954#25279954)

Comment: Some relevant answers [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17762214/243373)

Comment: Try Googling for ___jtable alternating row colors___

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because I was running NetBeans on dark mode. When I switched to light mode it works just fine.