# Set background color for particular row of JTable at runtime

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I am working with netbeans IDE7.4, I am adding rows to the `JTable` at run-time and now I want to set background color for a particular row.

Now the problem is that when the value of that row is changed the color of that particular row is not changed and when I scroll up or down the table the changes are applied.

How to refresh the table at run-time? How to set background color of particular row at runtime?

This is renderer class am using for coloring particular row:

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {         
public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected,     boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
   {
   final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,        column);

     Object val=table.getValueAt(row, 2);
     String sval=val.toString();
     sval=sval.replaceAll(":","");
     int ival=Integer.parseInt(sval);
  if(ival==0) 
    {  
        cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);          
        cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);              

    }      
    else  
    {      
        cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);      
        cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);      
    }    
    if (isSelected)
   {
    cellComponent.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());                             cellComponent.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
   }


      return cellComponent;

 }


 }
```

and am assigning to jtable like this :

```
    newViewTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new MyCellRenderer());
```

newViewTable is the name of JTable.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/2587435)

Comment: How are you updating the table/model (so it will change the cell rendering characteristics)?

Comment: Why not follow the advice I offered and post a MCTaRE rather than poorly formatted (unreadable) code that cannot be run and therefore is an example of nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, you need to tell the table that the content has changed in some way.

If you're using a `TableModel` based on `AbstractTableModel`, you can use the `fireTableXxx` events, for example `fireTableCellUpdate(row, col)`.  This will inform the `JTable` that the model has changed and cause it repaint the table...

You may wish to consider using `fireTablesRowsUpdated` as this will cause the `JTable` to update the entire row.

If you are using `setValueAt` on the model to change the value, you will need to call the appropriate event trigger...

**Updated with running example**

So, based on you `MyCellRenderer` renderer, I did this example, and it works fine...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                        new Object[]{"A", "B", "C"}, 
                        0
                );

                model.addRow(new Object[]{"A", "B", "1"});
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"C", "D", "0"});
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"E", "F", "1"});
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"G", "H", "0"});

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCellRenderer());

                JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{"N", "O", (int)(Math.round(Math.random() * 1))});
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            Object val = table.getValueAt(row, 2);
            String sval = val.toString();
            sval = sval.replaceAll(":", "");
            int ival = Integer.parseInt(sval);
            if (ival == 0) {
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);

            } else {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                cellComponent.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                cellComponent.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            }

            return cellComponent;

        }

    }

}
```

The question now is, what are you doing differently??

Comment: @user3331894 How are you updating the state of the row?

Comment: *"i cant post the whole source code"* Note that 'whole source code' != MCTaRE **or** 'runnable example'.  Nobody suggested you post the whole source code.

Comment: My Problem is solved...I used fireTabledatachanged..Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

> how to set background color of particular row at runtime?

Use a table cell renderer.  See [How to Use Tables: Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for details.