# JTable Set Cell Color At Specific Value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to write a method which for given parameters (value, color), sets color on the background of a cell which has value equal to cellValue.

What my method actually does is, it sets color on the background of a cells for whole row and when I select the row on the table, and I want method to only set color at specific column (where cellValue is equal to value) each time I call the method.

```
    void setCellBackgroundColor(boolean cellValue, final Color color) {
        List<List<Object>> data = tView.getTTableModel().getData();

        for (int row = 0; row < data.size(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < data.get(row).size(); col++) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = tView.table.getCellRenderer(row, Col);
                Component component = tView.table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                boolean bValue = 
                    TDataTypeRenderer.parseIntoRealValue(
                        data.get(row).get(col)
                    )
                );
                if (bValue == cellValue) {
                    component.setBackground(color);
                }
    }
```

Comment: and prepareRenderer is good and proper of possible ways (has column and rows coordinates), but is part of override JTables methods not to loop inside row & columns, result renderer (prepareRenderer) should be only one instance that loops inside view, note prepareRenderer hates empty JTables view, have to test if rows > 0 before call(s) is/are painted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> when I select the row on the table, and I want method to only set color at specific column

Try with overridden `prepareRenderer()` method as suggested by @mKorbel.

sample code:

```
Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
Object[][] data = { 
        { "abc", new Double(850.503), 53, true },
        { "lmn", new Double(36.23254), 6, false }, 
        { "pqr", new Double(8.3), 7, false },
        { "xyz", new Double(246.0943), 23, true } };

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
        if (getSelectedRow() == row) {
            if (value.equals(false)) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else if (value.equals(true)) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.green);
            } else {
                comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

When selected first row:

[image]

When selected second row.

[image]

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735007/how-to-set-color-to-a-certain-row-if-certain-conditions-are-met-using-java)

---

#### EDIT

As per your last comment

> Is it possible to change color with out clicking (selecting) row on the table?

Yes just remove the check of selected row.

```
    Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
    if (value.equals(false)) {
        comp.setBackground(Color.red);
    } else if (value.equals(true)) {
        comp.setBackground(Color.green);
    } else {
       comp.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: prepareRenderer is good and proper way, OP issue that her/his code loops inside JTables view and to add bunch of renderers

Comment: Thank you guys, now I understand where is the problem.

Comment: @Xerath I have update my code to select only cells of selected row.

Comment: Hey again, but this is only selecting when I click on the table. Is it possible to change color with out clicking (selecting) row on the table ?

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to use this with the Netbeans GUI Builder? I know how to use Customize code. But can't seem to work it out.