# How to change the color of particular cell in jtable in dynamic way (according to the input)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have an issue in JTable, when I choose selected value from drop down box it won't change the color of particular cell?
My task to is change only those cell color which is selected from drop down box. I mean to say when I select value1 from drop down box.. same cell of Value1 must highlight and other cell value keep as it is..?

```
    private void searchPatient(){
   String value = cmbSearchBy.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
   String id = txtSearch.getText();

   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
   jTable1.setModel(model);
   jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CellHighlightRenderer());
   jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        final TableColumnModel colModel = jTable1.getColumnModel();
        for(int column=0; column<jTable1.getColumnCount();column++){
            int width = 15;
            for(int row=0; row<jTable1.getRowCount();row++){
                TableCellRenderer render = jTable1.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component component = jTable1.prepareRenderer(render, row, column);
                width = Math.max(component.getPreferredSize().width+1, width);
            }
            if(width>300){
                width = 300;
                colModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
            }
        }

   try {
       String searchQuery = "select pcno, name, NRIC, emailid, contactno from n_patient where "+value+"=?" ;
       pst = con.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
       pst.setString(1, id);
       rs = pst.executeQuery();

       ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
       Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<String>();

       int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
       for(int i=1; i<=colCount; i++){
           colNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
       }

       Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
       while (rs.next()) {
           Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            data.add(vector);
       }


       model.setDataVector(data, colNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the TableCellRendere class is here

```
    public class CellHighlightRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

    private static final TableCellRenderer RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component component = RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if(column==0){
            Object result = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            int cellValue = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
            Color color = Color.GREEN;
            component.setBackground(color);
        }
        else if(column==1){
            Object result = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            String cellValue = result.toString();
            Color color = null;
            component.setBackground(color);
        }else if(column==2){
            Object result = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            String cellValue = result.toString();
            Color color = Color.GREEN;
            component.setBackground(color);
        }else if(column==3){
            Object result = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            String cellValue = result.toString();
            Color color = Color.GREEN;
            component.setBackground(color);
        }else if(column==4){
            Object result = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            int cellValue = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
            Color color =  Color.GREEN;
            component.setBackground(color);
        }
        else{
            component.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    return component;
    }
}
```

[Here is the Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfIRW.png)

[Elements of Drop Down Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFRB8.png)

Comment: Is there a drop down where user can select "pcno"? I don't see such a drop down in the screenshot.

Comment: PCNO, NRIC, EMAILID, CONTACTNO these are the four value of Dropdown box..!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080951/jtable-set-cell-color-at-specific-value) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @DevilsHnd, Now I will implement it with the help of this.